# addRole() Error - Call to a member function addRole() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am currently attempting to add a role to a user account using Symfony2 / FOSUserBundle.

Following the examples, and previous SO questions I have the following in my controller:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use MyVendor\MyBundle\Entity\Account;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    private function addRole($role, $username)
    {
        //Get the enity manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //Get the user with name admin
        $dbuser = $em->getRepository("MyVendor\UserBundle\Entity\User")->findBy(Array("username" => $username));
        //Set the role
        $dbuser->addRole('ROLE_BASIC_TRIAL');
        //Save it to the database
        $em->persist($dbuser);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

However when running the method I get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function addRole() on a non-object in .....\MyVendor\MyBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 52
```

Apologies if I've missed something obvious - this is my first Symfony2 project.

Comment: Are you sure a user with the given username exists? Also, findBy will return an array. Try replacing findBy with findOneBy

Comment: It looks like `$dbuser` is null, check with `if (null !== $dbuser)`

Comment: @FuzzyTree that worked perfectly thank you - I spent around 2 hours trying to find examples as to what I had done wrong. If you make it an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findBy() returns an array. Try replacing it with findOneBy()